# Ef code first with existing database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

Suppose I have two database tables, say `tb1` and `tb2`, with

```
[tb1]
id      primary key
name
lastname

[tb2]
id      primary key
tb1_ID  foreign key
phone_no
degree
grade
```

Relationship `tb1` may hold multiple record of table two. i.e: one to many relationship.

For this relationship I need an entity that hold all column of `tb1` one and only one column on `tb2` (say only ph no.). 

Suggest me the easiest possible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it work correctly or not 

Give it a try

```
Public class tb1
{
public int id{get; set;}
public string name{get; set;}
public string lastName{get; set;}
[NotMapped]
public List<string> relatedPhoneNo{get; set;}
}




var data = db.master.Select(t1 => new tb1
            {
                id = t1.id,
                name = t1.name,
                lastName = t1.lastName,
                relatedPhoneNo= (from t2 in db.tb2
                       where t2.id==t.id
                      select t2.city ).ToList()
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way - create database view and map it as a new entity. The better but more complex way - map those tables directly and use projection in LINQ query to your custom type:

```
var data = context.TB2s.Select(t => new TBViewModel
                                        {
                                           Id = t.TB1.Id,
                                           Name = t.TB1.Name,
                                           LastName = t.TB1.LastName,
                                           PhoneNumber = t.PhoneNumber
                                        });
```

Comment: your code is for one to one mapping but i need something for one to many

Answer (score -1):

Do you really have an existing database with data or do you just want EF Code First to generate a database that will look like that existing database design?

EF can create a database that looks like that if you just make two separate classes in your MVC3 Model (assuming you're doing MVC3 based on your tags).

Here is an example using Students and Courses:

```
 public class Student
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    //This should make the 1 to many relationship to the second table 
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }

}

 public class Course
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CourseName{ get; set; }

}
```

In this case EF Code First would create a table Student with a 1 to many relationship with the table Courses.

The resulting database would look like this:

```
[Student]
id      primary key
name

[Courses]
id      primary key
CourseName
Student_ID  foreign key
```